# Smooth transition to make element appear

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, transition

When I click on the button, I would like the arrow to appear by sliding out smoothly.  I'm currently doing this by adding the 'show' class if the arrow should be shown.  I've tried display: none; -> display: inline-block  I've tried width:0 -> width: 100%.
This code makes the arrow appear/disappear onclick, but without a smooth transition.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    span {
      -webkit-transition: all .5s;
      -moz-transition: all .5s;
      transition: all .5s;
      width: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      max-width: 0;
      display:none;
    }
    .show {
      width: 100%;
      display: inline;
    }

  </style>
  <script>
    function toggleArrow(elemId) {
      let elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
      if (elem.classList.contains('show')) {
        elem.classList.remove('show');
      } else {
        elem.classList.add('show');
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div> Here's the button:
    <button onClick="toggleArrow('title-arrow')">my button<span id="title-arrow" > ↑</span></button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it works right?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    button{
      position:relative;
      padding-right:20px;
      overflow: hidden
    }
    span {
      -webkit-transition: all .5s;
      -moz-transition: all .5s;
      transition: all .5s;
      overflow: hidden;
      top:50px;
      position: absolute;
      right:5px;
    }
    .show {
      top:0;
    }

  </style>
  <script>
    function toggleArrow(elemId) {
      let elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
      if (elem.classList.contains('show')) {
        elem.classList.remove('show');
      } else {
        elem.classList.add('show');
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div> Here's the button:
    <button onClick="toggleArrow('title-arrow')">my button<span id="title-arrow" > ↑</span></button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was very helpful. I added the show class to the button element, and the transition to buttons. Finally: button.show{padding-right: 20px;} and span.show{opacity: 1;} made the arrow (in its padding) emerge from the button onClick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Elijah if it answers for your question. You can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it appear, you can use

```js
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  element.style.opacity = 1;
});
```

```css
#element {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

then when you click the button, the arrow element fades in in one second.

Comment: Thanks! I used the opacity in my solution.  I commented it in a prior answer.  Thank you for the suggestion!